# Problem with the -c option and latexmk

Tags: latexmk, cleanup

Let assume that I want to compile the document doc.tex with `latexmk` and clear the processing files. When I do `latexmk -c doc.tex`, it gives me the following output :

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 11 Nov. 2012, version: 4.35.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Latexmk: Examining log file 'doc.log' for generated files...
```

and nothing, the document isn't compiled. But if I do successively do `latexmk doc.tex` then `latexmk -c doc.tex`, the document is compiled at the first step and the processing files are removed at the second step.

So my question is, why the first method doesn't work, and how to do it in only one step ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `texdoc latexmk`

```
-c
Clean up (remove) all regeneratable files generated by latex and bibtex or biber except dvi,
postscript and pdf. These files are a combination of log files, aux files, latexmk’s database file of
source file information, and those with extensions specified in the @generated_exts configuration
variable. In addition, files specified by the $clean_ext configuration variable are removed.

This cleanup is instead of a regular make. See the -gg option if you want to do a cleanup then a make.
```

The keyword is **instead** in the last sentence.

Comment: Thank for your answer. So I understand why my first command doesn't work. But is it any way to compile and then clean up in only one command ?

Comment: @P.-A. AFAIK there isn't, btw why do it that way? Then next time you compile it has to compile several times because you deleted the auxiliary files

Comment: @P.-A. You may try `latexmk doc.tex && latexmk -c doc.tex`...

Comment: please read the latexmk manual, I know it is impressive but to understand the -gg option it will be worthwhile

Comment: @PaulGaborit I was looking for a more "compact" solution, but it seems to do not exist. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @BernhardKleine I read it. The `-gg` option don't do the trick : it cleans and then makes, whereas I want the opposite, make and then clean.